# How to add more then one space (whitespaces?) in a string?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm looking, for various almost mystical reasons, to have a string containing more than one spaces. Basically, I want to be able to have a text string that, when compiled into an SWF, will show "     ".

I'm sure it is possible but... How?

Comment: Is this a trick question? I do not get it. please provide an example

Comment: I exchanged the space characters with `&nbsp;` to clarify the question - there actually were 5 spaces between the quotes...

Comment: Thanks @weltraumpirat ! Didn't saw the quotes where not showing right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is within an xml document, you might want to set [`XML.ignoreWhitespace=true;`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#ignoreWhitespace) and [`XML.prettyPrinting=false;`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#prettyPrinting)

This will ensure that any whitespace (spaces, tabs and line breaks) are not compressed to a single space.

It also helps to have `<![CDATA[ ]]>` tags around your text, in some cases.

Comment: Sadly, no, they're not in an XML document. But this is still good insights to keep in mind !

Comment: Are you using the `htmlText`property on the textField? Are you using TLF text?

Comment: I wasn't using TLF. But as I as said, this was good insight. Some of t he info where taken off an XML, so I just rewrote everything that wasn't working so now I takes the infos too from the XML. No problems anymore. I'd have wished to solve that quickier but, hey, that's what you have to do when you dig into code your employer outsourced! :) I'm going to give this answer my vote, as it's the one that finally led me to something that worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to revisit some of the basics.

```
myString:String = " ";

myString:String = " " + " ";

myString:String = "        ";
```

Comment: But outputing myString:String to the screen will only show " " here.

Comment: What are you using to output ? trace() ?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this would come down to the font you are using. Stringing spaces I believe tend to show up as 1 space. Try using a coding style font like Lucida Console.

Comment: But I can't change the font, sadly... (It's not a test output, but an actual needed output in the swf.)

Comment: Probably. But I don't have it. It's a complex situation, I'm digging into someone else's code (they outsourced everything back then) that is some month old, and I don't have everything sadly.

I finally rewrote pretty much of everything to make it work now...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old questions but for future visitors here is the answer

use space between quotes and remember to add a plus sign between words.

For example

```
trace("Three spaces here" + " " + " " + " " + "Two spaces after this  ");
```

Remember that text is in quotes and variables are not.  Anything between quotes is considered a String.

This is helpful to know when using dynamic text fields.

For example

```
this.some_text_field.text = String("I am" + " " + ageVar + " " + "years old");
```

The spaces can also be before or after text.

Hope that helps!

:)